Correcting data loss when converting from Revit to IFC
It was noticed that some approximations, element losses and data losses occur when Revit models are converted to IFC models. There is also change in coordinate of certain elements especially floors and walls. How can this be corrected when updating Revit with elements modified in the IFC?
All changes need to happen programmatically through APIs or Revit Add-ins.
I tried converting a model from Revit to IFC and expected the coordinates and elevations to remain the same but it did not.

Welcome to stackoverflow. I would suggest adding relevant source code to show your approach when converting your model.

Just to clarify, how exactly are you converting the Revit design to IFC? Looking at the tags on this post I assume it's the Model Derivative service? And if so, could you please share an example Revit design with us (confidentially) via aps.help@autodesk.com, and explain the data loss you're noticing on the IFC output?
